# Replace 'ae' inside a word into 'ä' while typing

Tags: microsoft-word

Can this be done? I think the standard AutoCorrect only works on whole words...

Comment: Not off topic if it's done via a VBA script.

Comment: What about changing your keyboard layout to Swedish/German/SomeOtherLanguageWithUmlauts instead? :-)

Comment: 1. This is off-topic. 2. I don't think there's something for this built-in. 3. What's wrong with search/replace ae->ä, oe->ö, ue->ü. I guess you can even write a macro for this. 4. Bad for words like "Aerodynamik" where you don't want it replaced...

Comment: @shnaader: Although I do agree with your 2-4, this really isn't off-topic if the OP is trying to do this using VBA - which is a safe assumption if you look at the tags.

Comment: @shnaader: I know from ExcelVBA that you can run a macro on a certain action (e.g., cursor leaves cell). Maybe something similar exists in word that can be applied here. My text will contain only very few 'false positives' such as Aerodynamik. I don't want to use search/replace, because the width of each word must be correct while I type.

Comment: @Tomas: OK, fair point.

Comment: Would you be happy with a macro that ran with an atl+key combination, rather than when ae is typed? It is possible, AFAIK, to use on change, but I do not think it is a great idea to constantly check.

Comment: Here are the available events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140279(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Is there any reason that Ctrl+Shift+: (press all three of these, then let go and then press) + **a** is not being used if you want this *as you type*?

Comment: @Otaku Good point, I found a list : http://www.starr.net/is/type/kbh.html#intl

Comment: @Frank I find that you do not have to change the layout (see list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution: Bind `wdKeyE` to the following macro

```
Sub my_e()
  Select Case (Selection.Previous(wdCharacter, 1))
    Case "a"
      Selection.TypeBackspace
      Selection.TypeText ChrW(228)
    'other cases, as desired 
    Case Else
      Selection.TypeText "e"
  End Select
End Sub
```

The key binding can be done with:

```
KeyBindings.Add KeyCategory:=wdKeyCategoryMacro, Command:="my_e", KeyCode:=wdKeyE
```

And unbinding:

```
Sub e_unbind()
  Dim cmds As Variant
  Dim bind As KeyBinding
  For Each bind In Application.KeyBindings
    If bind.KeyCategory = wdKeyCategoryMacro Then
      cmds = Split(bind.Command, ".")
      If cmds(UBound(cmds)) = "my_e" Then bind.Clear
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

...Works well so far

Answer (score 0):

As this has been migrated to SuperUser, it seems reasonable to include some of the comments as an answer.

@Otaku noted that a combination of keys would produce the required accent, based on this comment I found a list that details the accents that can be added with key combinations and an English or US keyboard layout. This is apart from the accents that can be got by using Alt Gr.

Comment: @Otaku this really belongs to you, so if you wish to reply, I will delete this community response.